# ViewPager with static content

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I want to create application which structure can be simplified as this:

[image: look]

Where Events tab has static content in our stackoverflow world, and is not reloading when app is working. So we can simplify it as a ViewPager.

Problem is with reloading Home tab, because when we set option in Drawer, accurate fragment should replaced Home tab.

**Question**

So here is my question, is it something similiar to ViewPager which replace current window from right side ? Because I replacing fragment in view pager is quit hard, so I want to replace home fragment in traditional way.

Comment: What is the problem to update home fragment? I think this is the logical choice on drawer select => update home fragment (not replace).

Comment: I will have to replace fragment in Home tab and didn't find working example with good performance and possibility to giving fragment to stack because when we press back button I want to get previous fragment.

Answer (score 0):

I`m not sure what your problem is. You don't want to update home fragment, you just want to replace it, so replace it and notify viewpager adapter for your change, save preview fragment before that and override back button press logic to replace again whit backuped fragment.

Comment: How to update fragment in your opinion? For example inbox is completely different thing fragment than sent mail.

Comment: Easy step is to have child fragment inside your Home fragment. The idea of fragments in android is that you have replaceable blocks whit logic and views.

Comment: Could you write sample code ? it seems to be great solution !